# Center the last element in the flex container, not the first one

Tags: css, flexbox

How can center the last element and not the first one.

The code:

```
.impress-profiles {
    .flex() //less mixin for flexbox
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    li {
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
}
```

The html is a simple list:

```
<ul class="impress-profiles">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: can u update ur html code

Comment: Sorry I meant "the last element and not the first one". But I updated the question. Please check the image, and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the last element in the list a `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.impress-profiles {
    .flex() //less mixin for flexbox
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    li {
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    li:last-child {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Here is a Fiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/fb4bo9d6/